# Customise contribution thank you page

Tags: wordpress, civicontribute

I'm new to CiviCRM, but done a lot of playing around for a new activist network I'm a part of. It's a brilliant tool! We are building our site in wordpress.

Becoming a member of our network is free, and we've created a contribution page to collect a few details from individuals. We'd like to edit the "thank you" page that users are sent to once they have completed the contribution page, so that it's cleaner and easier to read, and (most importantly) doesn't have the information about a membership fee - we're worried this will confuse people, even though it will of course say £0.00, because they are not paying anything.

Any tips on how to edit this page? And apologies if it's glaringly obvious ;)

Comment: Usually the best way to alter the page would be in an extension - potentially using jquery or css to hide the field

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to use a Contribution page to collect a few details. You can do this via a [Profile](https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/organising-your-data/profiles/) so it may make more sense to direct contacts to the Profile if they are not donating at the same time

Answer (score 2):

The easiest answer to the question as asked is Fuzion's [Front End Page Options](https://civicrm.org/extensions/front-end-page-options) CiviCRM extension.  It allows you to specify an alternate "thank you" page, which you can create freely in WordPress.

A programmer could also write an extension that modifies the thank-you page, but this option requires knowledge of PHP.  However, this option allows you to pull in variables from the person's contact/contribution records.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed with Pete that if you're not collecting payment, a profile is preferable to a contribution page.  If you need more flexibility than profiles allow, also consider using [Caldera Forms](https://wordpress.org/plugins/caldera-forms/) with [CiviCRM integration](https://github.com/mecachisenros/caldera-forms-civicrm).  Drupal and Backdrop CMS users with similar needs should use [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm) with [CiviCRM integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_civicrm).